# Return with no value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, return

I'm a beginner in PHP and JavaScript and have questions about "return with no value".

1. Do **#codeA** and **#codeB** have the same meaning?
   I'd like to know role of "return with no value inside the functions".
2. Is there any difference between **#codeB** and **#codeC**?
   I'd like to know if there is difference between **"return"** and **"exit"**, in exemple codes.
3. If **#codeB** and **#codeC** have same function, which format is preferred over another?
4. Would the answers "1, 2, 3" be the same in JavaScript?

## codeA

```php
function doFunction() {
 if(!conditionA) {
 //do something
 }
}
```

## codeB

```php
function doFunction() {
 if(conditionA) return;
 //do something
}
```

## codeC

```php
function doFunction() {
 if(conditionA) exit;
 //do something
}
```

Comment: "codeC" won't work in JavaScript because there's no `exit` statement.

Comment: **codeA** is return nothing, **codeB** return null, **codeC** exit the PHP, nothing after this can be execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer you

1. In your limited example they may be functionally equivalent, so yes they have apx the same meaning (see below)
2. Return exits the function scope, Exit ends PHP execution (see below)
3. see number 1 (see above, then see below)
4. No JS is not PHP, there is no "exit" for example

Below:

A lot of the differences are with what happens after, For example:

codeA

```
function doFunction() {
 if(!conditionA) {
     //do something -- only runs when conditionA is false
 }else{
    //do something else -- only runs when conditionA is true
 }

  //do something something else -- runs rather true or false
  //this could be before
}

 doFunction();
//do something something something else  -- runs rather true or false
```

codeB

```
function doFunction() {
 //do something something else --  runs rather true or false

 if(conditionA) return;
 //do something -- only runs when conditionA is false
 //do something else -- only runs when conditionA is false

}

 doFunction();
//do something something something else  -- runs rather true or false
```

codeC

```
function doFunction() {
 //do something something else --  runs rather true or false

 if(conditionA) exit;
  //do something -- only runs when conditionA is false
  //do something else -- only runs when conditionA is false
} 

 doFunction();
//do something something something else  -- only runs when conditionA is false
```

So from the standpoint of a limited sense they are the same, but B does nothing when `conditionA is false`.  And for C if it's true your script ends, if its not then it continues after execution exits the function `do something something something else`.

As for which one to use, depends on the situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess it was very messy question, lot of minus lol...
It's all clear now after reading your comments. 
I really appriciate you!